# Java: Handling of null & undefined values from HTTP GET

Tags: java

For below code, I'm expecting set of parameters coming with HTTP request.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {    
  int variable1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value1"));
  int variable2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value2"));
  int variable3 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value3"));

  if (variable1 == 1) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

However, I am getting this exception, because not all parameters always pass.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

What is the method I should use to handle undefined and null parameters?

P.S: code simplified to show needed case.

Comment: What behaviour do you want when the parameter is missing?

Comment: First check if parameter exists by `if (request.getParameter("value1")!=null)`.

Comment: You may use ternary operator e.g : `int variable1 = request.getParameter("value1") !=null ? Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("value1")) : -1;`

Comment: @khelwood just to be ignored, since I will have `if` function for each one (only one will match)

Comment: @arnaud: consider adding your thoughts as an answer instead of "just" a comment. This allows to give them the credit they deserve, ie becoming the accepted answer.

Comment: @Eng7 So `if (request.getParameter("value1")==null) { return; }` then...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own method that gives default values in case a parameter is missing:

```
private int getIntValue(String inputValue, int defaultValue) {
    return inputValue!=null?Integer.parseInt(inputValue):defaultValue;
}
```

And then you can use it like:

```
int variable1 = getIntValue(request.getParameter("value1"), -1);
...
```

Furthermore, you may want to check if the parameters are numerical and integer indeed. If not, then you expect to receive a `NumberFormatException` also. So, you can also include exception handling in the method:

```
private int getIntValue(String inputValue, int defaultValue) {
    try {
        return inputValue!=null?Integer.parseInt(inputValue):defaultValue;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Why not `Integer.parseInt` instead of `Integer.valueOf`, since you want an `int` rather than an `Integer` ?

Comment: @khelwood Yes, you are right, `Integer.parseInt` is better because you avoid unboxing. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Eng7 I'm not sure I understand what you mean asking to `use the name convention used in the question`. Could you please explain?